# Character vs char with arrays and array lists?

Tags: java, arrays, char

Why are Character arrays not valid, but char arrays are, and why are Character lists valid, but char lists not? This probably has something to do with primitives vs objects, but can someone explain it more clearly?

Comment: "Why are Character arrays not valid"—Who says they are not?

Comment: You are right on spot. `char` is a primitive type. `Character` is the object type. Google a bit about their difference and autoboxing.

Answer (score 2):

both `char[]` and `Character[]` are perfectly valid. When it comes to generics, though, (like those in `List<T>`), the generic parameter must be a class and not a primitive, so you can only have `List<Character>`.